# Makefile: declare PHONY targets as recipe prerequiste

Tags: makefile

My Makefile is bundling recipes to process large numbers of files in parallel (`make <recipe> -j8`, etc). But before files can be processed, they need to be found with `find`. This is a time consuming operation, so I only want to run it for the exact recipe that the user invoked. I can do it like this:

```
test: FILES=$(shell find "$(SEARCHDIR)/" -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type f ! -regex $(SOMEREGEX))
test: $(FILES)
$(FILES):
    echo "do thing with file $@ here"
```

The problem is that since the files inherently exist already, they need to be declared as `.PHONY` in order for the recipe to run, like this:

```
.PHONY: $(FILES)
```

But in order for this to work, the `FILES` variable needs to exist and be populated, which requires me to run the `find` command. This goes against my goal of not performing the search to find `FILES` until `test` is invoked. What I need is something like this:

```
test: FILES=$(shell find "$(SEARCHDIR)/" -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type f ! -regex $(SOMEREGEX))
test: .PHONY: $(FILES)
test: $(FILES)
$(FILES):
    echo "do thing with file $@ here"
```

But `test: .PHONY: $(FILES)` is invalid syntax and does not work.

Comment: Just to be clear, your `$(FILES)` recipe doesn't actually produce a file specific to its target, is that right?

Comment: @Beta Correct. Its actually deleting the files found in `FILES`, in other cases converting symlinks to files, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your makefile already doesn't work, even without the `.PHONY` thing; just:

```
test: FILES=$(shell find "$(SEARCHDIR)/" -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type f ! -regex $(SOMEREGEX))

$(FILES):
        echo "do thing with file $@ here"
```

fails because `$(FILES)` in the target of the rule expands to the empty string when `make` parses the makefile, before it's started to run the `test` target.

I recommend that you use recursive make here; write your makefile like this:

```
FIND_FILES :=
FILES :=
ifneq ($(FIND_FILES),)
FILES := $(shell find "$(SEARCHDIR)/" -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type f ! -regex $(SOMEREGEX))
endif

test:
        $(MAKE) test-recurse FIND_FILES=1

test-recurse: $(FILES)
$(FILES):
        echo "do thing with file $@ here"
.PHONY: test test-recurse $(FILES)
```

Comment: FWIW, the reason I didn't just have the `find` command in the recipe for the recursive make, as in `$(MAKE) test-recursive FILES='$(shell ...)'`, is because you said there were a lot of files and if there are a LOT of files you can run out of environment space and the recursive make command won't work.  If there aren't enough to make this a concern then doing this and avoiding `FIND_FILES` and the `ifneq` is definitely simpler and more clear.

Comment: I had been looking at recursive solutions for this but when I need to pass extra args to the original command, like `make test -j4 ARG1=foo ARG2=bar ...` etc, then I have to hard-code in passing all the args to the recursive `$(MAKE)` call?

Comment: looks like the answer that is here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html#Variables_002fRecursion

Comment: You don't have to do any of that.  All command line options and overrides are auto-magically provided to sub-makes, if you use the `$(MAKE)` variable (or `${MAKE}`) to invoke it.

Comment: I should be very clear: although all command line options and variable overrides are automatically given to sub-makes, _targets_ given on the command line are not passed to submakes (that wouldn't make sense).  But since here you only want to run a particular target anyway that should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. I switched over to using this format, and its working well so far.